# How could I filter duplicates?

Tags: php, sql, filter, phpmyadmin, duplicates

*INFORMATION:*

TABLE = giveaway

FORM 1 = id

FORM 2 = username

FORM 3 = userid

FORM 4 = wish

*END OF INFORMATION*

I am trying to make it filter through duplicate usernames and userids

NOTE: people enter the userid and the username (it is for a giveaway)

can anyone post me some code to do that?

Comment: Please give more information. Do you want to filter the input of a form so you can find if the input is already in the database or do you want to visualize the duplicated values in the database?

Comment: no I want it so that it filters the duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT  `username`,`userid` FROM `giveaway` group by `username` HAVING COUNT(`username`) > 1 UNION SELECT `username`,`userid` FROM `giveaway` group by `userid` HAVING COUNT(`userid`) > 1
```

Comment: I get a syntax error for an unexpected T_VARIABLE

Comment: I have no Idea where to put that but I will give you the acceptence

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table test;
/
create table test
(
id number,
username varchar2(20),
userid number,
wish varchar2(40)
);
/
insert into test
values(1,'A',1,'ZXX');

/
insert into test
values(1,'A',1,'YYY');

/
insert into test
values(1,'B',2,'ZXX');
/

SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT ID ,USERNAME,USERID,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY USERNAME,USERID) AS CNT
FROM TEST
)
WHERE CNT <2
```

This will give you unique values